# LinearLayout - Add the content dynamically when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

My app have the screen with linear layout in which displays all my controls (check box, radio button, drop down list etc). When we are showing the screen it loads all the controls (1000 controls) and displays it. Its taking more time it load and display all the controls. So instead of this, is it possible to display only 10 controls on the screen and when we scroll down, another 10 controls is dynamically loaded and displayed on the screen.

I am using linear layout and I don't want to use listview.

**Edit**

I can't use listview, because all of my controls are not in single row. For example checkbox control as row1 and date display at row2, radio button or edit text as row3 etc. These all controls are coming from server dynamically. So here i can't use the listview as u suggested.

Comment: A list with 1000 controls? Sounds like you should consider a complete refactoring of your layout/ui design... Do you really expect someone to scroll through 990 controls to access the last one? Make subcategories and create a navigational UI...

Comment: Hello my friend, it's not a way to develop any UI. please give us your view of application and purpose of application for your app UI design.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit argument is just wrong. A row is a logical unit, not a predefined thing. What you put inside the row, even more than one of your control, is totally up to you.

You really need to use a ListView and dynamically change what you show in your rows. Like you said: In row 1 you put a checkbox, row 2 gets a date display and row 3 has two thinks like TextView and on/off toggle. It is up to you to make a construction for that but seriously: Use a ListView!

Beside that: The UX of this would be awful and a perfect example for a "don't" list. Structure the controls that come from the server somehow. Each setting screen has some categories like "sound", "video", "notifications"... make the same for your controls! I really doubt that you can't somehow categorize the controls you get.

You should work on that to prevent a UX disaster...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but then you'll just be implementing things like lazy loading, and end up with an adjusted LinearLayout which can scroll and load your data based on your scroll position. 
To do it nicely you'll create some separate class which you can call an Adapter and which will handle the loading for you.

And then you realize you created a bad version of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant solution for loading dynamically different types of views in a container is to use some sort of container that extends [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html).
That way you can implement an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) that can create all the views that you need.
This is a very efficient way, as it reuses the views that scroll out of bounds instead of creating every view it will need.

In my code I use a container that extends `AdapterView<ListAdapter>` and it works great.